# How do you do custom validation on FileHelpers?

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I want to throw an exception to say that we have an invalid email address as I dont want to proceed until we get a valid email address. Is this where I want to do it and if so, how?

```
void Engine_AfterReadRecord(EngineBase engine, FileHelpers.Events.AfterReadEventArgs<UserInfoFromAd> e){
     bool isEmailValid = IsEmailValid(e.Record.Email);
     if (!isEmailValid){
        //I want to throw exception
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be the problem? Just throw it:

```
if (!isEmailValid)
{
    throw new InvalidDataException("Email is not valid.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Throwing the exception in the `AfterReadRecord` event is fine, but you need to set the [`ErrorMode`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.ErrorMode.html) to `SaveAndContinue`.  This tells the engine to save the error to `Engine.ErrorManager.Errors` and continue importing.  After the import you can process the errors.

Here is an example program:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class MyClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<MyClass>();
        engine.AfterReadRecord += new FileHelpers.Events.AfterReadHandler<MyClass>(engine_AfterReadRecord);
        engine.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;
        // import a record with an invalid Email
        MyClass[] validRecords = engine.ReadString("Hello|23|World");
        ErrorInfo[] errors = engine.ErrorManager.Errors;
        Assert.AreEqual(1, engine.TotalRecords); // 1 record was processed
        Assert.AreEqual(0, validRecords.Length); // 0 records were valid
        Assert.AreEqual(1, engine.ErrorManager.ErrorCount); // 1 error was found
        Assert.That(errors[0].ExceptionInfo.Message == "Email is invalid");
    }

    static bool IsEmailValid(string email)
    {
        return false;
    }

    static void engine_AfterReadRecord(EngineBase engine, FileHelpers.Events.AfterReadEventArgs<MyClass> e)
    {
        bool isEmailValid = IsEmailValid(e.Record.Email);
        if (!isEmailValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Email is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guys.. I guess mainly my concern was if throwing a type of exception will pose some issues... thanks again..@Petr @shamp00